# angular 4 - how to display json array in vertical fashion

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

From backend I am getting json array of say Notes (one json is one Note) i.e

```
 [
  {
    "StrategyName": "ClearBridge Aggresive Growth fund",
    "ProductType": "MF",
    "FirmName": "ABC",
    "Complement": "",
    "TakeOver": "",
    "PlatformFirm": "",
    "PlatformName": "",
    "topics": [
      {
        "title": "Strategy/Objective",
        "text": "System to allow Owner modify product notes and save as a new note."
      },
      {
        "title": "People",
        "text": "This allows Owner to quickly create a note for different vehicle types by cloning the existing, This allows Owner to quickly create a note for different vehicle types by cloning the existing, This allows Owner to quickly create a note for different vehicle types by cloning the existing"
      },
      {
        "title": "Philosophy/Process",
        "text": "Process content"
      },
      {
        "title": "Roles",
        "text": "Currently has 40% foreign exposure"
      },
      {
        "title": "Positioning",
        "text": " test Positioning content "
      },
      {
        "title": "Composition",
        "text": " test Composition content "
      },
      {
        "title": "Performance",
        "text": " test Performance content "
      },
      {
        "title": "Current Allocation",
        "text": "Current Allocation "
      },
      {
        "title": "Miscellaneous",
        "text": "Miscellaneous Content "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "StrategyName": "JhanCock Global absolute Ret",
    "ProductType": "MF",
    "FirmName": "BCD",
    "Complement": "",
    "TakeOver": "",
    "PlatformFirm": "",
    "PlatformName": "",
    "topics": [
      {
        "title": "Strategy/Objective",
        "text": "test strategy"
      },
      {
        "title": "People",
        "text": "test people"
      },
      {
        "title": "Philosophy/Process",
        "text": "Process content"
      },
      {
        "title": "Roles",
        "text": "Currently has 30% foreign exposure"
      },
      {
        "title": "Positioning",
        "text": " test Positioning content 2 "
      },
      {
        "title": "Composition",
        "text": " test Composition content 2 "
      },
      {
        "title": "Performance",
        "text": " test Performance content 2 "
      },
      {
        "title": "Current Allocation",
        "text": "Current Allocation 2 "
      },
      {
        "title": "Miscellaneous",
        "text": "Miscellaneous Content 2 "
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In angular I am using MaterialTable . I am able to display one note in one row.

### Name, FundType, FirmName, topic1, topic2, topic3   (Header row)

ClearBridge Aggresive Growth fund,MF,ABC,topic1, topic2 , topic3 ..

JhanCock Global absolute Ret,MF,BCD, topic1, topic2, topic3..

But requirement is to display in vertical fashion

Name  -      ClearBridge Aggresive Growth fund ,   JhanCock Global absolute Ret

FundType -     MF   ,                                 MF

FirmName  -    ABC     ,                              BCD

topic1    -    topic1 ,                              topic1

topic2     -   topic2 ,                               topic2

topic3    -    topic3,                                topic3

Data is array of Note i.e Note[]  (in materialtable , this.dataSource.data = data as Notes[];)
I was looking to create another array of say NoteDisplay[] . NotDisplay[] will have data in vertical fashion.
Please guide if any other approach can work ?

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: material-table is most fit with modified data for display. saw multiline list, but it will be coming in one column only (one after another) it looks, it will not fit here.